# Tinkercad: Function return user-defined class "does not name type" in Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I had been writing a simple game on Arduino Uno using Tinkercad's simulator. I created  a class named Bullet and a class named MainCharacter, I put it directly into the code editor of Tinkercad since it cannot be imported multiple .h and .cpp files like a normal Arduino compiler.

```
class Bullet{
    private:
        int xLocation;
        int yLocation;
        int flySpeed;
        bool isBetween; 
    public: 
        
        Bullet(int flySpeed){   
            this->flySpeed = flySpeed;
        }
        
        int getX()        {    return xLocation;}
        int getY()        {    return yLocation;}
        int getFlySpeed() {    return flySpeed;}
        bool getIsBetween()  {    return isBetween;}    
        
        void setX(int xLocation)          {    this->xLocation = xLocation;}        
        void setY(int yLocation)          {    this->yLocation = yLocation;}
        void setIsBetween(bool isBetween) {    this->isBetween = isBetween;}        
};
```

```
class MainCharacter{
    private:
        int xLocation;
        int yLocation;  
    public:
        MainCharacter() {}
        
        int getX() {    return xLocation;}      
        int getY() {    return yLocation;}
            
        void setX(int xLocation){    this->xLocation = xLocation;}
        void setY(int yLocation){    this->yLocation = yLocation;}
};
```

This is how my code would look like (simplified)

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#define ... //something

class Bullet{//above};
class MainCharacter{//above};

int game(){ //something};

Bullet spawnBullet(int flySpeed, int locationY)
{
    Bullet bl = Bullet(flySpeed);
    bl.setY(locationY);
    bl.setIsBetween(true);
    bl.setX(LENGTH_X_MAX);
    
    return bl;
}

void setup{
   //something
   static MainCharacter mc = MainCharacter();
   mc.setX(1);
   mc.setY(0);
}
void loop{
   game();
}
```

When I compiled, I received the error `'Bullet' does not name a type` point to the `spawnBullet` function. I don't understand why the compiler didn't accept a function which returned a user-defined class in this case, while the `int game()` could work. I have tried to move the class sections around, above the #include, or under the setup section (if I delete out the `spawnBullet()` function, things worked perfectly, as you can see the MainCharacter constructor call under `setup()` still functioning well).

Very appreciate who can point out my mistake. I have spent an entirely evening for this dumb error and I am hopeless now.

This is the link for my Tinkercad project: https://www.tinkercad.com/things/fWqGvbNHamj-terrific-wluff/editel?sharecode=c2_J2v4jdWwJRrVpS7k3-LPJlEf_F5z082RSwWXUhY4

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask] again! Point is, nobody here even knows where this error occurs (quote it including line numbers!) and also you should extract a [mcve] first, so the amount of code to read is reduced reasonably. Lastly, make sure you researched what the error means, just put it into the search bar above.

Comment: "_I received the error 'Bullet' does not name a type point to the spawnBullet function._" Please copy-paste entire errors, instead of trying to paraphrase them. They might've included vital information, that you glossed over.

Comment: Hi thank for your respond, the error under Tinkercad's compiler "12:1: error: 'Bullet' does not name a type   exit status 1" points to line 12 which is a blank line (that's why I don't really trust this compiler of Tinkercad but I don't have any other ways to do). I repeatedly tried to delete the spawnBullet() function above so I'm pretty sure the compiler should point the error there.

Comment: Also, due to Tinkercad's one file editor so I did not included any header into the file (you can see above), I just put the class code directly into the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used tinker cad before, but I managed to get your project to compile.

Here's my change to the declaration of spawnBullet(), this more or less comes from C, even though some c++17 features like auto do work in tinker cad.

```
class Bullet spawnBullet(int flySpeed, int locationY)
{
    //...
}
```

The main .ino file of (classic) Arduino projects being preprocessed to generate a .cpp file, I think the problem comes from the preprocessor used by autodesk.

I would expect such an error should not be present in tinker cad, but this workaround should at least allow you to advance on your project.  This is also probably not compatible with other arduino preprocessors, so you should expect to have to modify the code if you move development of the project to a local computer.

Comment: I don't know what to say except thank you a billion! I really feel the frustration of working under a very limited simulating system where I have no control of. Your modification helps me a lot  as now I can advance my project. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: The pleasure is all mine.

Comment: @DuyHà  I've edited the title of the question, so others can find this solution more easily on search engines.